# Convert to 2.5 IDE laptop using SATA drive

Tags: ssd, sata, pata

I've got an older laptop that I'd like to soup up with a sata ssd that I just have happened to have lying around. Is there anyway to squeeze it in there? I believe they are both 2.5.

I'm considerin just booting off of it as a USB drive ( i have an external enclosure) but I figure the IDE port would be faster.

Is there such a mini adapter? ( converter)

If I have usb2.0, could it be potentially just as fast to boot off of the USB port?

Comment: If you have USB3, then you'd get the same speed. USB2 will be significantly slower though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are very different interfaces - so its not a 'simple' swap 
standard USB 2.0 is fast enough for running an OS off, in many cases, but using an SSD drive on USB is a waste.

Comment: I'm running it off of USB 2.0, that's not too shabby. While the SSD is probably being slowed down, it's not significant in comparison to the native (likely 5400 RPM drive), and when you factor in the seek times, the difference is insignificant enough that I can't tell which is faster.